# Getting Detailed SSRS Errors

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in `SSRS` (SSRS 2008, running on Windows 2008 Server, running in Sharepoint integrated mode) that is returning an error.  However - I have no idea what the error is.  If I run the report on the Report Server, I'm returned this error message.

[image]

Crystal clear, right?

I have enabled Remote Errors via `Reporting Services`, so I believe I can get the error by querying the ReportServer database by this:

```
SELECT * FROM ExecutionLogStorage
ORDER BY TimeStart DESC
```

I see the report I ran, but "Status" is "rsSuccess".

The AdditionalInfo field returns:

```
<AdditionalInfo>
    <ProcessingEngine>2</ProcessingEngine>
    <ScalabilityTime>
        <Pagination>0</Pagination>
        <Processing>0</Processing>
    </ScalabilityTime>
    <EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
        <Pagination>4</Pagination>
        <Processing>18</Processing>
    </EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
    <DataExtension>
        <SQL>1</SQL>
    </DataExtension>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

From that, it looks the report ran successfully, but it obviously didn't.

When I look through the SSRS logs, located here: 
I see this:

```
library!ReportServer_0-9!abc!12/02/2013-13:52:47:: Call to GetPermissionsAction(http://ReportServer/reports/Documents/BlackList_Report.rdl).
library!ReportServer_0-9!11a4!12/02/2013-13:52:47:: Call to ListParentsAction(http://ReportServer/reports/Documents/BlackList_Report.rdl).
library!ReportServer_0-9!d54!12/02/2013-13:52:47:: Call to GetPermissionsAction(http://ReportServer/reports).
library!ReportServer_0-9!1c2c!12/02/2013-13:52:47:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
library!ReportServer_0-9!abc!12/02/2013-13:52:47:: Call to GetPermissionsAction(http://ReportServer/reports/Documents/BlackList_Report.rdl).
library!ReportServer_0-9!11b4!12/02/2013-13:52:48:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('http://ReportServer/reports/Documents/BlackList_Report.rdl')
runningjobs!ReportServer_0-9!a70!12/02/2013-13:54:18:: i INFO: Adding: 1 running jobs to the database
```

Again, nothing that explains what the error is.  How can I figure out what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright - I was able to configure `Sharepoint` to display the actual error. It has nothing to do with `SSRS`.

To get the full `Sharepoint` error, you need to make some changes in the `web.config` file, which is typically located in the following directory: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories`.

The changes you need to make are:

Find this entry:

`<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false">`

and replace it with:

`<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="true">`

Lastly, change:`<customErrors mode="On" />` to `<customErrors mode="Off" />`.

Save the file.  I did not need to reboot Sharepoint for this to work.

Now Sharepoint should provide a detailed error message.